# Why does apache always returns 000-default instead of other virtual hosts?

Tags: apache, virtual, host

I try to setup two domains on one server, using apache and virtual hosts.  I created one conf-file for each domain, but it seems that apache is always using 000-default instead of my own conf-files.

This is my directory structure:

```
/var/www# ls -al
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  236 Mär 11 16:21 .htaccess
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       43 Mär 28 05:22 index.html
drwxr-xr-x 5 www-data www-data 4096 Mär 28 05:02 domain-1.de
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Mär 28 05:13 domain-2.de
```

I think I have enabled both domains:

```
ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Mär  7 09:18 000-default -> ../sites-available/default
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 Mär 28 03:56 domain-1.de -> ../sites-available/domain-1.de
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Mär 28 03:56 domain-2.de -> ../sites-available/domain-2.de
```

This is the content of my own conf-file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain-2.de
    ServerAlias www.domain-2.de
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain-2.de
</VirtualHost>
```

I restarted apache as root (service apache2 reload).
But no matter which domain, the only page that is shown is the index.html in /var/www.

This is the content of /var/log/apache2/error.log:

```
[Mon Mar 28 07:15:02 2016] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Mon Mar 28 07:15:02 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) PHP/5.4.45-0+deb7u2 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: `service apache2 restart` make any difference. Maybe try sudo too

Comment: Please add the URLs you request.

Comment: And what is this "more domain-2.de " doing in there?

Comment: @Sarcoma I restarted apache, but that does not help.

Comment: @arkascha Removed the "more domain-2,de" that was not part of the conf-file. The URLs I request are domain-1.de and domain-2.de.

Comment: Those are not URLs, but domains, however lets leave it with that. What does your http servers error log file say when you restart the process?

Comment: @arkascha Added the content of the error.log in the post.

Comment: The normal behavior of the default configuration in debian based distributions is that only those files are considered in those folders, that end on `*.conf`. Everything else is ignored. It might be that your http server simply does not use those files you created. Take a look yourself at the `IncludeOptional` configuration statement in your apache configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution.
In the other_vhosts_access.log there were multiple entries like

```
[28/Mar/2016:09:50:11 -0500] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 304 212 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"
```

Http return code 304 means 'Not Modified', so the page was not transferred again. After clearing the browser cache, everything works as expected.

thx!

Comment: A request will never be served from a cached version of a reply to another domain! Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps

1. ## sudo nano /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerName  website.localhost
  ServerAlias www.website.localhost

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot "/Users/Username/Sites/website"

  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn

  ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
  CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common

    <Directory /Users/Username/Sites/website>
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
         Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

2. Allow the vhosts configuration from the Apache configuration file httpd.conf

   ## sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Search for ‘vhosts’ and uncomment the include line
Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
This will allow usage of the http`enter code here`d-vhosts.conf file, open this file to add in the vhost.

3. ## sudo nano /etc/hosts

   127.0.0.1       website.localhost
4. ## sudo apachectl restart

   You can replace ErrorLog and CustomeLog or check the error `enter code here`/private/var/log/apache2/